# Searching date and time in Lucene query string in Cloudant

Tags: lucene, cloudant, nosql

I am trying to write the index and search using date and time in that index in Cloudant NoSql database. 
When I pass only the date in the query string, it works fine

```
created_date:[2015-08-16 TO 2015-08-27]
```

This returns the correct results but when I include time in the parameter:

```
created_date:[2015-08-16 07:38:00 TO 2015-08-27 07:38:02]
```

I get an error:

```
Cannot parse 'created_date:[2015-08-16 07:38:00 TO 2015-08-27 07:38:02]': Encountered " "TO" "TO "" at line 1, column 50. Was expecting one of: "]" ... "}"
```

I have some more query parameters before this but the above is the gist of the error.

This is an Apache Lucene query string. What is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it the following way

```
created_date:["2015-08-16 07:38:00" TO "2015-08-27 07:38:02"]
```

and used the keyword analyzer in cloudant

This link explains it all
https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

Answer (score 4):

According to **Lucene** Java doc, date format should looks like this:

> A date field shall be of the form 1995-12-31T23:59:59Z The trailing
>   "Z" designates UTC time and is mandatory
>
> This format was derived to be standards compliant (ISO 8601) and is a
>   more restricted form of the canonical representation of dateTime from
>   XML schema part 2. Examples...
>
> 1995-12-31T23:59:59Z 1995-12-31T23:59:59.9Z 1995-12-31T23:59:59.99Z
>   1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z

So, you miss 'T' between date and time.

For more information: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_10_4/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html